# How to calculate totals from an action event using Javafx

Tags: javafx, combobox, actionevent

I'm having trouble visualizing how to go about calculating the subtotal, tax, and total in the following. I am trying to get my calculations done inside the action event. The reason for this is that, when a selection is made from the combobox and added to the list I need to figure my calculations. Then if I deselect an item it would subtract from the subtotal and total. There will be no calculate button. Can someone tell me if I'm thinking correctly on this. I have tried so many different things but keep getting errors. I really don't have any examples to go off of and I really am having a hard time visualizing this. Can someone please give me an example that points me in the right direction?

```
 double bcost[] = { 1.95, 1.50, 1.25, 2.95, 2.50, 1.50 };
    double acost[] = { 5.95, 6.95, 8.95, 8.95, 10.95, 12.95, 6.95 };
    double mcost[] = { 15.95, 13.95, 13.95, 11.95, 19.95, 20.95, 18.95, 13.95, 14.95 };
    double dcost[] = { 5.95, 3.95, 5.95, 4.95, 5.95 };
    String[] beverages = { "Soda", "Tea", "Coffee", "Mineral Water", "Juice", "Milk" };
    String[] appetizers = { "Buffalo Wings", "Buffalo Fingers", "Potato Skins", "Nachos", "Mushroom Caps",
            "Shrimp Cocktail" };
    String[] maincourse = { "Seafood Alfredo", "Chicken Alfredo", "Chicken Picatta", "Turkey Club", "Lobster Pie",
            "Prime Rib", "Shrimp Scampi", "Turkey Dinner", "Stuffed Chicken" };
    String[] dessert = { "Apple Pie", "Sundae", "Carrot Cake", "Mud Pie", "Apple Crisp" };


 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 ComboBox<String> beverageComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    ObservableList<String> items1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(beverages);
    beverageComboBox.getItems().addAll(items1);

    Label bo = new Label("Beverage Ordered");
    pane.add(bo, 2, 5);

    ListView<String> list1 = new ListView<String>();

    beverageComboBox.setOnKeyPressed((e) -> {
        list1.getItems().add(beverageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    });

    list1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
        list1.getItems().remove(list1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    });

    pane.add(list1, 3, 5);
    GridPane.setRowSpan(list1, 5);
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ComboBox<String> appetizerComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    ObservableList<String> items2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(appetizers);
    appetizerComboBox.getItems().addAll(items2);

    Label ao = new Label("Appetizer Ordered");
    pane.add(ao, 2, 10);

    ListView<String> list2 = new ListView<String>();

    appetizerComboBox.setOnKeyPressed((e) -> {
        list2.getItems().add(appetizerComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    });

    list2.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
        list2.getItems().remove(list2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    });

    pane.add(list2, 3, 10);
    GridPane.setRowSpan(list2, 5);

 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: setOnAction() won't help you here

Comment: And, one more thing, if you want multiple selection then why aren't you using list or check boxes instead of combobox? Combobox is not the correct choice for this.

Comment: When you say combobox is not the correct choice, what do you mean?? I am supposed to use a combobox and add my selections to a listbox. Can you please give me some suggestions? I can't think of any other way to get the totals other than when they are added to the listbox?

Comment: You are better of using a list or checkboxes. If the person could have only one beverage, then combobox would have sufficed but if multiple beverages can be had, then list is a better design choice.

Comment: So as the items are added to the list box I can't get totals somehow out of the listbox??

Comment: Yeah. Write a method and execute it every time a selection/deselection occurs.

Comment: I've tried writing a method and eclipse keeps telling me that it has to be final

Comment: Forgive the stupid question -- does the method have to be in s certain area of a javafx program??

Comment: I can give an example based on checkboxes or listview...

Comment: I'll take anything at this point---Thank you I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Making Some checkboxes:

```
chkHockey = new CheckBox("Hockey");
chkBaseball = new CheckBox("Baseball");
chkFootball = new CheckBox("Football");
```

Declare them as instance variables and not as local variables. If you do declare them as local variables, either maintain created checkboxes in a list or pass the object into the handler function when adding an event. So, that you can use them inside the handler function.

Making 2 labels for testing:

```
lbltotal = new Label("Sports chosen: 0");
lblChoices = new Label("None");
```

Attaching click-method to all the checkboxes. You can use a loop to add the handlers if you put all the checkboxes in a List.

```
chkHockey.setOnAction(e -> handleButtonAction(e));
chkBaseball.setOnAction(e -> handleButtonAction(e));
chkFootball.setOnAction(e -> handleButtonAction(e));
```

The handler function:

```
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent e) {
    int count = 0;
    String choices = "";
    if (chkHockey.isSelected()) {
        count++;
        choices += chkHockey.getText() + "\n";
    }
    if (chkBaseball.isSelected()) {
        count++;
        choices += chkBaseball.getText() + "\n";
    }
    if (chkFootball.isSelected()) {
        count++;
        choices += chkFootball.getText() + "\n";
    }
    lbltotal.setText("Sports chosen: " + count);
    lblChoices.setText(choices);
}
```

Although the example that I've given is quite basic, the approach can be used to do any manner of calculation on events. If you can do count, then you can do other calculations as well provided that you have access to the concerned variables in the handler function.

In case of listview, you can use changeListener() to do the same job. Here, the calculation is happening when a checkbox is ticked; In the case of listview, the calculation will happen whenever a change in selection occurs. [Check out JavaFX listview](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm).

---

**Update:**

1. Make the ComboBox Objects and ListView Objects instance variables instead of local variables. Initialize these objects in the `start()` method.
2. Create a method that will be called each and every time a value is added or removed from the ListViews. In this method, do all your calculations. Since, all the ListViews are instance variables, you can access them from this method without passing them as parameters.

Set change listener to ListViews as follows:

```
list1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String old_val, String new_val) -> {
    changeHandler(); // This method will contain the calculations
});
```

3. Add change listeners to all the ComboBoxes to populate the ListViews.

Example change listener for one of your ComboBoxes:

```
beverageComboBox.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
    list1.getItems().add(beverageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
});
```

Given the above snippet, you can populate your ListViews.

Comment: silly question in javafx is listview the same as a listbox

Comment: @jedi Yes. Check out this - http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm

Comment: One more silly question hopefully.. So this is a clip of the directions--The application should display all the menu items listed below in four ComboBoxes.
Each ComboBox should contain a category of food offered by the restaurant (Beverage, Appetizer, Main Course and Dessert).
Keep track of the items ordered by placing each item selected from the ComboBox into the associated ListBox.
As each item is selected, add the price of that item to the bill.-------Is this possible with a method assuming I can figure that out???

Comment: I'll be honest I'm lost but Thank you for the help.

Comment: @jedi Yes it is. Again, you need to use changeListeners() for comboboxes as well as the listview.

Comment: I added a button that calculates. I'm  trying to calculate  using parallel arrays. I tried the changelistener but no luck it wouldn't work.  It has to be the answer to what i'm trying to do. can you show me in my code where the changelistener would go??

Comment: I have been trying to get this without any help and I am still stuck. According to my professor it can be done with .bind-- and a class called bill. Do you know anything about bind? I have about 24 hrs to get this going and I don't feel confident in this one.

Comment: Also I got rid of the calculate button

Comment: Yes. You can bind value properties of components. Don't know how that is going to help you here. It is generally used for sliders.

Comment: I am going to post all of my code can you take a look at it?

Comment: Can you see it?? I have never used pastie.org.

Comment: You have to give me the link

Comment: Yes. Can you clearly state what you want the program to do?

Comment: The application should display all the menu items listed below in four ComboBoxes.
Each ComboBox should contain a category of food offered by the restaurant (Beverage, Appetizer, Main Course and Dessert).
Keep track of the items ordered by placing each item selected from the ComboBox into the associated ListBox.
As each item is selected, add the price of that item to the bill.
Allow an item to be deselected, i.e. if an item is clicked in the ListBox it should be removed from the ListBox and the price of that item should be subtracted from the bill.

Comment: The user should be able to click the Clear Bill Button to restore the Subtotal:, Tax:, and Total: fields to $0.00.

Comment: Man... This is a small project in itself... I can't address everything but I'll update my answer to maybe give you an approach...

Comment: I didn't add the rest of it because I was able to do it

Comment: Will I know when you have updated? Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: ok I will but so far I'm still lost. None of this is in the book. This is supposedly a new assignment he is testing out and I am not a fan of it.

Comment: It is better you try and make smaller applications and get habituated with handling various events.

Comment: I hope your still on here. I have been working with this. How do I access the prices?? No matter what I do I get an error for                                                                             subtotal = (bcost[beverageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()]);      I don't know how else to access this array

Comment: also when adding your code it will not let me deselect an item from the listbox

Comment: scratch the comment I thought I was supposed replace the lines of code. I added the lines and we are good. I still don't get how to access my bcost array that has the prices

Comment: are you available for a few minutes

Comment: When? You see, I do have a job.